# How to configure Gnome 3 on Ubuntu-19.04 Virtual Machine running on my Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome3, gnome-shell, google-cloud-platform, tightvnc

I am able to follow these links to configure **Gnome 2** onto my VM in GCP successfully.
[Installing and configuring Ubuntu Desktop for Google Cloud Platform](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/big_data_and_business_intelligence/9781788474221/1/ch01lvl1sec15/installing-and-configuring-ubuntu-desktop-for-google-cloud-platform)

[Graphical user interface (GUI) for Google Compute Engine instance](https://medium.com/google-cloud/graphical-user-interface-gui-for-google-compute-engine-instance-78fccda09e5c)

I am using Remmina on my ubuntu-19.04 on my local pc to establish a VNC connection to the VM on google cloud which is running a **tighvncserver**.

This is how my present desktop (inside GCP VM) looks like from Remmina. [GNOME 2 Shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yljrS.jpg)

This is how I want it to look like [GNOME 3 Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiMkL.png)

We are required to edit the `~/.vnc/xstartup` script for the VNC session to work properly as described in the links above. But these configurations are old enough and using `metacity` which renders a Gnome2 session.

How to run a Gnome 3 (complete desktop experience) on my Google Cloud Virtual Machine which looks and feels exactly like **Ubuntu 19.04**.

**What changes do I need to make to the **`~/.vnc/xstartup` **script to be able to render a Gnome 3 session?**

Answer (score 0):

> [enter image description here][1]
>
> Try This:
>     [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIUa0.png

Comment: I suggest you use code markdown in your answer rather than linking to an image of the code on an external site. The answer will be much simpler to use and and search for, and it will remain available here independently of the availability of the external resource. Additionally linking to the original source is always good if you are referencing someone else's work.